# Display and hide bootstrap spinner within function

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

**Problem**
A bootstrap spinner needs to display during/ while a function is executing. Once the function has finished executing the spinner should no longer display.

I have the following bootstrap element:

```html
<div id="resultsSpinner" class="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
```

The css for the spinner is as follows:

```css
.spinner-border {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    display: none; /* displays nothing initially*/
}
```

I have the following js:

```js
function doesSomething() {
    //does stuff here
    
    const spinnerBorderEl = document.querySelector('.spinner-border');

    spinnerBorderEl.style.display = 'initial'; //should change the display from none to its initial state, so that it displays
}
```

The problem I have is that the spinner doesn't display at all with the above. FYI, it displays on the page if I remove 'display: none;' from the css file, but I obviously can't control it then like is required...

**I have also tried**
I have attempted to run the code a few different ways, but without any luck. One of the other ways was through using the following. Again, I had no luck...

```js
function showLoader() {
        $(".spinner-border").fadeIn();
        };
showLoader();
```

Any directions much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Html (with added class .spinner):

```
<div id="resultsSpinner" class="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span class="spinner spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-3" role="status" aria-hidden="true">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

Add css to css-file:

```
.spinner {
    display: none; 
}

body.busy .spinner { display:block !important; }
```

Or use visibility:

```
.spinner { visibility:hidden; } 
body.busy .spinner { visibility:visible !important; }
```

js file:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
  $('.spinner-border').on('click', function()
  {
    $('body').addClass('busy');
  });
});
```

When done, do:

```
$('body').removeClass('busy');
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul. I'm afraid it doesn't work for me with either of your solutions mentioned above. If I remove the spinner-border class (from the css file) the spinner shows. If I keep the spinner-border class (in the css file) and keep display as 'none' it doesn't display at all...

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
spinner.style.display = 'none' # hide the spinner

# eventlistener for your button function
document.getElementById('funcButton').addEventListener("click", () => {
    spinner.style.display = 'inline-flex' #show the spinner
    
    button_function() 

    # if your button_function is an async function, do not put the line of code that hides your spinner here:
    spinner.style.display = 'none' # don't put it here! 

});


const button_function = async () => {
    
    #fetch or do some blocking action
    
    # add the end of the function, hide the spinner
    spinner.style.display = 'none' 

};
```

The reason is the async function is non-blocking, what might happen is the spinner will display and hide in an instant, without appearing to display.